# Why does Docker use the same user and cgroup namespaces by default, when starting a new container?

Tags: linux, docker, debian

> Why does Docker use the same user and cgroup namespaces by default, when starting a new container?

I don't understand why Docker doesn't set up a new user namespace, so that `root` in the container isn't the same as `root` on the host.

In particular, since everything else is namespaced (besides cgroup), it really makes no sense not to completely isolate the container by default.

Can someone clarify why user namespaces are not enabled by Docker by default?

**Host namespaces:**

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ ls -la /proc/self/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 cgroup -> cgroup:[4026531835]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 ipc -> ipc:[4026531839]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 mnt -> mnt:[4026531840]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 net -> net:[4026531957]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 pid -> pid:[4026531836]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 user -> user:[4026531837]
lrwxrwxrwx 1 parallels parallels 0 Jan 30 17:29 uts -> uts:[4026531838]
```

**Container namespaces:**

```
docker run -ti --rm debian:latest
root@210189a7a164:/# ls -la /proc/self/ns
total 0
dr-x--x--x 2 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 .
dr-xr-xr-x 9 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 cgroup -> 'cgroup:[4026531835]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 ipc -> 'ipc:[4026532287]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 mnt -> 'mnt:[4026532285]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 net -> 'net:[4026532290]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 pid -> 'pid:[4026532288]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 user -> 'user:[4026531837]'
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 30 16:30 uts -> 'uts:[4026532286]'
```

The `user` and `cgroup` namespaces are the same for the host and container.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked to a group that deals with Docker internals and not a security group?

Comment: @schroeder - you might be right, but I've seen many experienced Docker security experts in here.

Comment: Sure, but this is a Dockers internal question, not a security question. Is there a place that you would prefer I migrate this to?

Comment: @schroeder - either "Super User" or "Server Fault", I guess those are the best places, if not here.

Answer (score 2):

As to the specifics of Docker's decision not to enable userns by default, you'd probably need to ask Docker, but I can offer a possible rational.

Docker's general design philosophy appears to have been to enable the use of containers while minimizing disruptions and complications to the development workflow.

Enabling user namespaces can cause issues with file/directory permissions when mounting volumes from the underlying host, as the uid/gid in use in the container may not have rights to mounted directories.

This can be addressed of course by careful management of those permissions, but it is a disruption.

User namespacing is available as an option, so it is still possible for individual organizations and users to enable it, it just needs to be setup.

It's worth noting that Docker are also working to enable "rootless" Docker support and this is available as an experimental option now (more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) ) and this would address the overall issue, by ensuring that no container (or the daemon itself) runs as root.

Comment: thank you! Besides issues with permissions of mounted host volumes, isn't it very easy to set up a user to emulate "root" within the new container? `"When a user namespace is created, the first process in the namespace is granted a full set of capabilities in the namespace."`. Furthermore, Docker's "rootless" mode basically only means to drop the unnecessary privileges as I understand it?

Answer (score 2):

It's basically the classic trade off between usability and security. I configured it for my developer desktop after [CVE-2019-5736](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2019-5736) was reported to be mitigated by user namespaces, and turned it off a few months later. It makes it very difficult to work with host volumes. That's not a big deal for a deployed cloud native application, but is huge if you use docker for devops purposes like CI builds or sysadmin tooling, or for legacy apps that depend on a lot of host files.

Compounding the problem was the fact that I was the only one having the problem, which of course wouldn't be the case if user namespaces were the default as you suggest, but the feature wasn't available until docker 1.10 and by then changing the default would have been too disruptive to existing users.

Comment: So, what you say is that, if user namespaces had been the default from the beginning, you wouldn't have faced all the issues you mention above, e.g. C/I builds, since you'd have designed your Docker containers accordingly then to work with host volumes?